# jQuery Ui autocomplete Not Getting Value From Php MySQL File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui auto complete but when i am trying to get the value from simple javascript variable i am getting but jquery Ui auto complete is not working with the php mysql file this is my code

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-12" class="col-centered">

                   <input id="tags" type="text" class="dic_input ui-autocomplete-input" data-provide="tags" name="ajaxData"/>
                   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
```

this is my javascript code

```
$(function() 
{ var availableTags = [
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: "auto.php",
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

this is my php code

```
$db=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("hifzil");

    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

    //get matched data from skills table
    $sql ="SELECT lemma FROM lemma WHERE lemma like '" . $searchTerm . "%' ORDER BY lemma LIMIT 0,6";

    $q=mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
        $data[] = str_replace("-"," ",$row['lemma']);

    }

    //return json data
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Soo many things are wrong with this code..read up on best php practices. In the meantime, please don't go live with this

Comment: i am working on local can you please find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible that this work, first you are doing avaiableTags in local but after at the source you put a remote source, your example it's the basic that you find in jquery but there the example is in local so at least source:avaiableTags, if you want to do a remote call you can use the code under but open with f12 the console log of the browser and after put your own of select item

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source:function(request,response){
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          data:{},
          url: "auto.php",
          dataType: "json",
          success:function(data){
               console.log(data);                         
           }
         });                                        
    },
    select: function(event,ui){},//your own at the selct item 
    change: function(event,ui){},//your own in change event
    response: function(event, ui) {}//your own in response 
    minLength: 1
});
```

and in the php i think the array is not correct... you must write

```
        $data[] = array('item'=>str_replace("-"," ",$row['lemma']))
```

And after in succe javascript you can write

```
                          success:function(data){

                                 items= data;
                                 listItem=[];
                                 for (i=0; i<items.length; i++){
                                   listItem[i] = items[i]['item'];
                                 }
                               response(listItem);                                
                           }
```

and the response will be the list of the items after in select event you can do your own at selection...etc..etc..but must use the console browser to see the answer.

Javascript :

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source:function(request,response){
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          data:{term: request.term},
          url: "auto.php",
          dataType: "json",
          success:function(data){
                             items= data;
                             listItem=[];
                             for (i=0; i<items.length; i++){
                               listItem[i] = items[i]['item'];
                             }
                           response(listItem);                        
           }
         });                                        
    },      
    minLength: 1
});
```

Php:

```
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hifzil");

$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

//get matched data from skills table
$sql ="SELECT lemma FROM lemma WHERE lemma like '" . $searchTerm . "%' ORDER BY lemma LIMIT 0,6";
$data = array();
$q=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $lemma = str_replace("-"," ",$row['lemma']);
    $data[] = array('item'=>$lemma);

}

//return json data
$result = json_encode($data);
print $result;
```

Comment: Are you sure the the sql it's correct? the code i insert work if the json encode is not emptyi tried now and it's work control the query on the db...[$i]['item'] in javascript is the key item in the json php...use mysqli_fetch_assoc not array.... and don't use mysql it's deprecated use mysqli ;)

Comment: yes because when i am trying to get the results via query string i am getting

Comment: i have uploaded the image you can see it

Comment: well so in the data of the ajax insert data:{term: request.term}, and use my mysqli_fetch_assoc and $data[] = array('item'=>$row['lemma'])

Comment: can you edit your answer here it will be very helpful for me i am working from 10 hours and stucked :(

Comment: I modified your code but i'm not in your computer so you must try if don't work...Bye...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159495/discussion-between-hotshot-code-and-spizzi).